# Calling a stored procedure from another SQL Server Database Engine

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

From SQL Server Management Studio I have connected to an SQL Server database engine. This database engine has a lot of databases. From a store procedure defined in a database I am trying to call a store procedure in another database that it is in another SQL Server database engine. So I have done:

```
exec [MyDatabaseEngine].[MyDatabase].[MyStoreProcedure] param1, param2
```

But it is not working.

I do not know if I have explained it correctly. If not, please let me know.

Comment: @SeanLange arrgggggg, yes... you are right! thx very much! Post the answer and I will vote you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the schema. The format is [LinkServer].[Database].[Schema].[Object]

Answer (score 2):

You need to have linked server created with credentials access to the other database. More info

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/linked-servers/create-linked-servers-sql-server-database-engine

Once you have it, you can run queries on another server

```
SELECT name FROM [SRVR002\ACCTG].master.sys.databases ;  
GO
```